# Two Factor verification being called twice on from post

Tags: django, django-two-factor-auth

I'm implementing django-two-factor-auth into a project I'm building.  I've gotten two factor to work with a base project without issues.  I'm currently running into a problem where the verification check for the token is run twice during post which causes authentication to fail.

To generate this issue subclass LoginView and add override post code below:

```
class Custom_Login_View(LoginView):

    template_name = 'two_factor/core/login.html'

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):

        return super().get_form(step, data, files)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form(data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES)
        form.is_valid()

        return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
```

It appears the issue is that `is_valid` is called both in my form and it's parent forms, which is why authentication happens twice.  It's very likely I'm doing something to cause my own issue, but I can't figure out how to prevent it, without editing something in django-two-factor-auth.

Am I missing something?  Is there a good workaround for this?  I think I know a good place to patch django-two-factor-auth to fix it, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Comment: Don't call `form.is_valid()` (you might also be calling `form.save()`) when you override and **also** call `super`. The super method is going to call that on the form anyway. If you think what you might be doing is not exactly compatible with the super method forego calling `super` entirely and bring the relevant logic to your implementation.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah I was trying to avoid that.  I need to call is_valid because there's some extra data I need to process first.  The code that actually calls is_valid the second time is several levels deep in dependencies, I'd rather not rewrite the whole implementation.  I'm currently interested if there's a way to call is_valid without the issue, or if this is just a "bug" in two-factor-auth.

Comment: It's not a "bug" as you say... It's simply **you** not being able to figure out where to add your code properly. From looking at the code you should be overriding [process_step](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/b8a4980079b8f56f954ec493538d0f07f0f941cc/two_factor/views/core.py#L231). As it is a multi stage form. Also the code as you say is not _"several levels deep"_ and not that complicated.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for the massive condescension, also process_step does not resolve this issue.  The is_valid call is only called during the "auth" step which is the username/password form.  The issue I'm running into is during the "token" step.  I just ran the code and proved that.  The is_valid I'm concerned about _is_ several levels deep, it's in the formtools plugin, called by two-factor-auth.  I don't think calling it a bug is incorrect as is_valid should be callable multiple times not once.  Regardless I have my answer, this is expected behavior without modifying two-factor-auth

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Apologies, it was rather late last night and I was focused on the specific problem I had.  You are correct I can remove the need for a second call to is_valid via process_step.  Though I do think that multiple calls to is_valid on the token form cause a failure is probably a bug.  Regardless I appreciate the help and if you'd like to add that as an answer I'll accept it.  Seems like your on an answer roll here so you might be interested.

Comment: I might have been a little harsh in my comment there, It was only the fact the you appeared to blame a problem as a bug (It appeared to me that the developers who developed the particular library had put good work in it and their code was proper). Anyway as a clarification being able to call form_valid multiple times is okay for other places, but here you are validating an otp hence it cannot and should not be validated multiple times (hence it is not a bug but in fact a feature). Anyway it is great that you have solved the problem. :)